# Работа с циклами в python

Tags: python, циклы

Проблема в работе кода, debug в PyCharm мне не помогает.
Расскажу про код на примере продаж, мне нужно совершить четыре действия:

1. При выполнении первого условия происходит первая покупка.
2. Далее, первая продажа. Зачем мне цикл cycles_b? Первую продажу мне необходимо произвести сразу после выполнения sec сondition. Поэтому делается проверка каждую секунду, при удовлетворении sec condition, сразу делается first sell и цикл прерывается функцией break.
3. Затем, по моей задумке совершается вторая половина кода/
4. После выполнения  sec sell, код должен начаться заново с перерывом в 5 секунд.

На деле, работает только первая половина кода, после first sell ничего не происходит. Я не знаю, срабатывает ли функция break, т.е. прерывается ли цикл cycles_b. И почему код не работает далее, fourth condition и тд?
Спасибо.

```
cycles_a = 1000
for _ in range(cycles_a):
    if first condition:
        first buy
        cycles_b = 500
        for _ in range(cycles_b)
            if sec condition:
                first sell
            if third condition:
                break
            time.sleep(1)
    if fourth condition:
        sec buy
        cycles_c = 500
        for _ in range(cycles_c)
            if fifth condition:
                sec sell
            if six condition:
                break
            time.sleep(1)  
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: пожалуйста используйте менее всеобъемлющие заголовки. Старайтесь, чтобы заголовок описывал именно вашу проблему [ask]

Comment: `if fourth condition` не работает, то это потому что не срабатывает то условие. Вам поможет отладка. Если не умеете/не хотите пользоваться отладчиком, можно отладку сделать через вывод print'ами в консоль, чтобы увидеть в каком моменте код перестал выполнять задуманное

Answer (score 1):

Если вы написали все верно, то ошибка здесь:

"Поэтому делается проверка каждую секунду, при удовлетворении sec condition, сразу делается **first sell и цикл прерывается функцией break**."

```
for _ in range(cycles_b)
    if sec condition:
       first sell
       break # делается first sell и цикл прерывается функцией break
    time.sleep(1)
```

И аналогично со второй половиной кода

```
for _ in range(cycles_c)
    if fourth condition:
        sec sell
        break # После выполнения sec sell, код начнется заново с перерывом в 5 секунд
    time.sleep(1)
time.sleep(5)
```